# ajax , actualizar varios contenidos div en misma consulta

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Necesito ejecutar en una misma funcion de ajax me retorne el contenido de varios divs, paso a detallar

index.php

```
<div id="contenidorespuesta1"></div>
<div id="contenidorespuesta2"></div>
<div id="contenidorespuesta3"></div>
<div id="contenidorespuesta4"></div>
 <script>
$( document ).ready(function(){
        //Perform Ajax request.
        var delay = 3000;
        var parametros = {
            "numerodesqueda" : $('#numerodesqueda').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros, 
            url:   'script.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'post', //método de envio
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loader").show();
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                       $("#loader").hide();
                        $("#contenidorespuesta1").html(response);
                    }, delay);                  
             },

    });
    });
    </script>
```

puse $("#contenidorespuesta1").html(response); me devuelve todo , y lo necesito por separado ya que son distintos bloques de respuesta.

script.php

//son 4 bucles de consultas mysqli , que me dan 4 bloques de resultados diferentes , como lo llevo a index.php por separado?

```
<? for($i=0;count($arrayuno);$++){ ?>
<div id="respuestauna"><?php echo $arrayuno[$i];?> </div>
<?php } ?>
<? for($i=0;count($arrayuno);$++){ ?>
<div id="respuestados"><?php echo $arraydos[$i];?> </div>
<?php } ?>
<? for($i=0;count($arraytres);$++){ ?>
<div id="respuestatres"><?php echo $arraytres[$i];?> </div>
<?php } ?>
<? for($i=0;count($arraycuatro);$++){ ?>
<div id="respuestacuatro"><?php echo $arraycuatro[$i];?> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Deberias agregar el contenido de `script.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer en tu script php devolver un json

ejemplo en tu archivo script.php:

```
$res1="";
$res2="";
$res3="";

///aqui van tus ciclos para rellenar tus $res ejemp: $res="<div>contenido</div>"


echo json_encode(array("contenidorespuesta1"=>$res1, "contenidorespuesta2"=>$res2, "contenidorespuesta3"=>$res3));
```

y en tu response de ajax

```
$.ajax({
            data:  parametros, 
            url:   'script.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'post', //método de envio
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loader").show();
            },
            success:  function (response) {
               setTimeout(function() {
               $("#loader").hide();
               $("#contenidorespuesta1").html(response.contenidorespuesta1);
               $("#contenidorespuesta1").html(response.contenidorespuesta2);
               $("#contenidorespuesta1").html(response.contenidorespuesta3);
               }, delay);                  
             },

    });
```

Comment: Gracias , juan ya mismo pruebo !

Comment: Como utilizo json_encode cuando la respuesta es un bloque de html y php , como el primer caso?, quiero levantar todo el contenido del div, no solo el array.
<? for($i=0;count($arrayuno);$++){ ?>
<div id="respuestauna"><?php echo $arrayuno[$i];?> </div>
<?php } ?>

Comment: lo manejas como una cadena ejemplo $res1.="<div>contenido".$algunvalor."</div>"

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta y velocidad de la misma , ya te digo como me va

Comment: Juan Carlos , funciona perfecto es tan simple como lo pusiste, mil gracias!!!